# How to generate 20 BASE-36 unique id in IOS ? sample unique id is here "KI21AJDIWJS239323112"

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to append a unique id while making server request to avoid duplicate request.

Comment: Yeah it should be like Device UDID but device UDID will not work for me.In my app i need to create unique id every time when i am making any server request.

Comment: ok. it will contain 40 char like this "31C7E9A9-D400-487A-84E5-F3322AD87077 ". is it ok?

Comment: that a base 16 number, not base 36.  But I would think that size of a number would be more than enough.

Comment: i am able to get an example of id which i need.                        Ex -"KI21AJDIWJS239323112"

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code for creating unique ID, use each item while hitting the service.

```
CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
NSString *uuidString = (__bridge NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuid);

NSLog(@"Uni ID %@",uuidString);
```

Comment: actually it is not working for me.i need base-36 number, which shouldn't contain "-" .It should look like something "KI21AJDIWJS239323112"